# Can I detect if the user click print or cancel after windows.print?

Tags: javascript, php, printing

I would like to know if there is any way to know if the user clicked print or cancel after the windows.print pop up because I need to update a database if the user print (PHP).I have seen posts about this but they are old, but currently it is possible?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can listen to the afterprint event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onafterprint

Comment: The onafterprint event is called even if the user clicks cancel.